# Java: Sort method throwing error: Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Hey i got this little code snippet that doesnt work when i run my programm. I have a list with Objects and want to first seperate them by 2 Types and then sort them alphabetically with their name. But when i run the programm there is always this java error which says : Comparison method violates its general contract!
I really hope somebody can help me.

```
List<RandomObject> list;
list.stream().sorted((o1, o2) -> {
    if(o1.getClass().equals(o2.getClass))
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    if(o1.getClass == someClass1.class && o2.getClass() == someClass2.class)
        return -1;
    return 1;
    })
```

Comment: What kind of objects does `list` contain? Does it have anything other than `someClass1` and `someClass2`?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes it contains more than just 2 types of objects but only 2 of them matter to me the other ones are "hidden" you could say.

Comment: What is `RandomObject`?  Where is the `getName()` method defined? How are the `someClass1` and `someClass2` variables defined? Why do you think your "hidden" objects aren't going to cause a problem?

Answer (score 2):

The 'general contract' is this:

(`a < b` here means: `a.compareTo(b)` returns a negative number).

- `a.compareTo(a)` *must* be `0`.
- If `a.compareTo(b)` is 0, `b.compareTo(a)` *must* also be.<sup>1</sup>
- If `a < b`, then `b > a` *is required*.
- If `a < b` and `b < c`, then `a < c` *is required*.

These rules seem extremely obvious, but it's harder than you might think.

Your code returns a blanket `1` when it has no idea, which trivially breaks the contract: It means if your code has no idea for `a` and `b`, then `a.compare(b)` and `b.compareTo(a)` are violating the contract (both returning `1` which is not allowed).

You've also clearly not followed SO instructions: You have written pseudocode or otherwise edited your actual code **without testing it**, and then pasted that. I know that because your code wouldn't compile (missing `()` after `o2.getClass`. Given that you have no idea what's happening (as you're asking SO questions), you have no idea what's important and what isn't, so it's also possible that the problem lies in what you ended up removing when transferring your actual code into this question.

[1] It is acceptable for 2 non-equal items to nevertheless be considered 'at the same level' by any given comparator/compare-implementation. What this means depends on what you're passing it to. For example, if you consider "foo" and "bar" as comparison-wise equivalent (`"bar".compareTo("foo")` returns 0, as does the reverse), then only one can be put in a `TreeSet`, but you can put both in a list and then `list.sort()` it, and that merely means they'll be sorted arbitrarily. However, your comparison op still needs to be consistent: `"foo"` and `"bar"` are not equal but a comparator can deem them 'equivalent', but you **must** then make it so that `compare("foo", "bar")` and `compare("bar", "foo")` / `"foo".compareTo("bar")` and `"bar.compareTo("foo")` **both** return `0`, or you're violating contract.